# Injecting props through higher order component causes compiler error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am trying to inject props into a component using a higher order component (hoc). I follow along this [article](https://medium.com/@jrwebdev/react-higher-order-component-patterns-in-typescript-42278f7590fb). This is my hoc:

```
// WithWindowSize.tsx
import React, {useEffect, useMemo, useState} from 'react'

interface WindowSize {
    width: number,
    height: number
}

export function WithWindowSize <T>(Component: React.ComponentType<T>) {
    return function WithComponent(props: Omit<T, "width" | "height">) {
        const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState({} as WindowSize)

        useEffect(() => {
            ...
        }, [])


        return <Component
            {...(props as T)}
            windowSize={windowSize}/>
    }
}

export default WithWindowSize;
```

And this is how I try to use the hoc `WithWindowSize`

```
// Foo.tsx
interface FooProps {
    headline: string,
    value: string | number,
}

const Foo = ({headline, value, windowSize}: FooProps) => {
    return ...
}

export default WithWindowSize(Foo);
```

But, this highlights the `prop` `windowSize` in `<Foo />`, and tells me

> Property 'windowSize' does not exist on type 'FooProps'.

Why is that?

Comment: Many devs moved to use hooks instead of HOCc because of things like this

Comment: "Why is that?" because `FooProps` doesn't have anything named `windowSize`, just like the error says.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I do not understand. If I pass `windowSize`  in `FooProps`, this would require me to always wrap `<Foo />` into the hoc... Is there no way to pass the prp `windowSize` in the hoc to the wrapped component?

Comment: What do you mean "wrap `<Foo />` into the hoc"? I'm not sure what "the hoc".

Comment: oh...higher order component...

Comment: You can always pass `windowSize` directly without using the hoc...at least as far as the types are concerned. But the whole point of `FooProps` is that it declares which props your component will accept. If you want your component to accept `windowSize`, then it must be declared as one of the props in `FooProps`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `{headline, value}: FoooProps`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `windowSize` prop in interface you have defined

```
interface FooProps {
    headline: string,
    value: string | number,
    windowSize: string | number
}
```

I also see there is one extra O in type `FoooProps` you have given is it some typo or other type than `FooProps` ?

Comment: This should not be needed and also would require me to always wrap `<Foo />` into the hoc...

Comment: You can and should export your HOC interface for these situations with Typescript. Because the "problem" here is not that your windowSize doesn't exist, is that Typescript doesn't know it exists. The solution would be something like. Add an interface to your HOC `export interface WindowContext { windowSize: string | number }`. And then you can simply extend your Props interface in every component you need to use your HOC `interface FooProps extends WindowContext {...}`